# building gtest framework on XCode 4.4.1

Tags: c++, xcode, testing, stl, googletest

I'm trying to build gtest for XCode 4.4.1 as per the instructions [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vND8C3bF5A&feature=relmfu) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/sidelight/wiki/gtestSample) ; however, it seems that upon trying to build "gtest-framework" the only possible destination in my "Scheme" is "My Mac 64-bit".

When I try to build the project, I get the following error :-

> The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'gtest-framework'. The
>   scheme 'gtest-framework' contains no buildables that can be built for
>   the SDKs supported by the run destination My Mac 64-bit. Make sure
>   your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of
>   Xcode.

How could I proceed with building gtest for XCode so that I can use it for my projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In General.xcconfig change values for SDKROOT and MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

```
// Default SDK and minimum OS version is 10.4
SDKROOT = $(DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR)/MacOSX10.7.sdk
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
```

In the projects Build Settings change the Base SDK to 10.7 and the Compiler to the default compiler.

Building gtest should work now.